# Highlight only the filtered items by pressing down or up arrow key

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create an autocomplete for my own purposes. Here the filtering is working fine. I also Want to Highlight the selected Item. But there is a problem. First take a look at my code and then I will explain the problem in detail.

Here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from '../../Models/person';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto-complete',
  templateUrl: './auto-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auto-complete.component.css']

})
export class AutoCompleteComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor() {}

    showSuggestions: boolean;
    query: string;
    people: Person[];
    selectedRow: Number;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.query = '';
        this.people  = [
            new Person ('Shane', 'Watson', 'Australia'),
            new Person ('David', 'Warner', 'Australia'),
            new Person ('Ricky', 'Ponting', 'Australia'),
            new Person ('Adam', 'Gilchrist', 'Australia'),
            new Person ('Andrew', 'Symonds', 'Australia'),
            new Person ('Sachin', 'Tendulkar', 'India'),
            new Person ('Rahul', 'Dravid', 'India'),
            new Person ('Virender', 'Sehwag', 'India'),
            new Person ('Mahendra', 'Dhoni', 'India'),
            new Person ('Virat', 'Kohli', 'India'),
            new Person ('Gautam', 'Gambhir', 'India')
        ];
    }

    inputFocused() {
        this.showSuggestions = true;
    }

    inputBlurred() {
        this.showSuggestions = false;
    }

    setClickedItem(index: Number) {
        this.selectedRow = index;
        this.query = this.people[+index].firstName;
        this.showSuggestions = false;        
    }

    setSelectedItem(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 40) { //down arrow
            if(this.selectedRow == null || this.selectedRow == undefined) {
                this.selectedRow = 0;
            } else if(this.selectedRow >= this.people.length - 1){
                this.selectedRow = 0;
            } else {
                this.selectedRow = +this.selectedRow + 1;
            }
        } else if(event.keyCode == 38) { //up arrow
            if(this.selectedRow == null || this.selectedRow == undefined) {
                this.selectedRow = this.people.length - 1
            } else if(this.selectedRow <= 0) {
                this.selectedRow = this.people.length - 1;
            } else {
                this.selectedRow = +this.selectedRow - 1;
            }
        } else if(event.keyCode == 9) { //TAB
            if(!(this.selectedRow == null || this.selectedRow == undefined)) {
                this.query = this.people[+this.selectedRow].firstName;
            }                    
            this.showSuggestions = false;            
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the template:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" (focus)="inputFocused()" [(ngModel)]="query" (keydown)="setSelectedItem($event)" />
  <table *ngIf="showSuggestions" (blur)="inputBlurred()">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let person of (people | textFilter : query); let i = index"
          (click)="setClickedItem(i)" [ngClass]="{'active': (i == selectedRow)}">
        <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here is the stylesheet:

```
table tr.active td {
  background-color:#123456 !important;
  color: white;
}
```

**Problem:**

When I press down arrow or up arrow on my keyboard, the next or previous item is highlighted. That's fine. But when I search using input box and then If I press down arrow or up arrow, the next or previous item in people collection is highlighted, it highlights the non visible items also. What I want is only highlight the filtered item by pressing down arrow or up arrow.

Comment: Could you please add `textFilter` code in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fLZfZBzraDgDeBeIUA5Z?p=preview) and add it in OP..

Comment: @PankajParkar I have updated the plunk.

Comment: where is the plunker link?

Comment: @PankajParkar https://plnkr.co/edit/goLatqRgOD8MGq2yITnE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the error is the following line:

```
    } else if(this.selectedRow >= this.people.length - 1){
```

Or more specific in all lines where you have this.people.length.

Don't forget. The length of people isn't chaning even though you don't display them. 
That means the selectedRowIndex will be reseted to 0 only when you went through all "filtered" people. So you have to get the lenght of the filtered people instead of all.

If you need help for this implementation don't hesitate to ask. But I think you can manage that on your own.

My approach for something like that would be:

- To make the pipe injectable.
- Inject it into the component
- Create a new property (filteredPeople)
- `this.filteredPeople = this.pipe.transform(this.people, /* PIPE Parms */)`
- Adjust the html to display the filteredPeople
- Adjust all places where you used people.length with filteredPeople.length

Hope this helps.